# AFNetworking 2.0 and simple JSON

Tags: xcode, afnetworking

I'm trying to use `AFNetworking` 2.0 consuming a simple json, the result from the json is:

```
{
    "solicitudId": "61898",
    "estado": "Atendida",
    "tipoPago": null,
    "monto": 23,
    "mayorDerecho": 0,
    "sistema": "SPRL"
}
```

I defined a class (solicitud.h solicitud.m) like this:

```
@interface SolicitudNSDictionary : NSDictionary

- (NSString *)solicitudId;
- (NSString *)estado;
- (NSString *)tipoPago;
- (NSNumber *)monto;
- (NSNumber *)mayorDerecho;
- (NSString *)sistema;

@end
```

the json is call here without error

```
- (IBAction)jsonButton:(id)sender {
    // 1
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@solicitud?id=61898&from=MOVIL&ip=172.9.1.14", BaseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // 2
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // 3
        self.solicitud = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        self.title = @"JSON Retrieved";
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    // 5
    [operation start];
}
@end
```

My problem is I don't know how implement the tableview from the NSDictionary, on the cellForRowAtIndexPath i tried but i have not luck.

I declared in the @interface

```
@property(strong) NSDictionary *solicitud;
```

and this variable is set here

```
// 3
        self.solicitud = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
```

Where I get error is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellName";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *solicitudTmp = nil;
    solicitudTmp = [self.solicitud];

    // You will add code here later to customize the cell, but it's good for now.
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.solicitudTmp solicitudId];

    return cell;
}
```

At this line

```
solicitudTmp = [self.solicitud];
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What's not working? What does "I don't know how implement the tableview from the NSDictionary" mean? What does the code you've shown have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

`solicitudTmp = [self.solicitud];` is a syntax error.

Objective-C messages exist in the format `[receiver message]`. The code above is missing a message.

What you probably intended was:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.solicitud valueForKey:@"solicitudId"];
```

That said, there's a lot of other really questionable stuff going on in this question:

- `SolicitudNSDictionary`, as a model, should be a subclass of `NSObject` that has an initializer that takes a dictionary (`NSDictionary` should not be subclassed)
- You should let AFNetworking take care of turning URL parameters into a query string.
- Your operation code could be improved by using an `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, instead of constructing requests yourself.

I would strongly encourage you to look at some additional resources before going forward. [Apple's Developer Site](http://developer.apple.com) has a number of programming guides and other reference material to help get you started.